# Why can't I sometimes share status on Facebook?

Tags: facebook

Any idea why sometimes I cannot share somebody else's status on Facebook? We are friends and some of their statuses I cannot share because the 'share' link is missing under their status.

It looks I can share whatever she shared but not her own updates.

Answer (score 3):

I would assume that this feature is restricted only to links and not status messages, as documented in the [Facebook help pages](https://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=116221138461586#How-can-I-share-a-link-that-someone-already-posted?)

Comment: OK, it looks like I can share status updates if they are 'shared with public' by the one who post it. If the permission is with friends the share link is missing.